# Authenticate with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Domain Name in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have successfully integrated Google OAuth2.0 (version google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1) in my iOS application. The problem is my custom domain authentication works on iOS 6.1 but the same does not work for iOS 7.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution. The problem is simulator. Google OAuth2.0 not authenticating custom domain for iOS 7 simulator. This works perfectly on device.